# NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement

Tags: java, sql

Helllo, I've been trying to create an Entity named ContratoAluguer, however each time I try to create this Entity the following error occurs:

```
Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO CONTRATOALUGUER (CLIENT_ID, AUTOMOVEL_ID) VALUES (?, ?) [23502-200]
Error Code: 23502
Call: INSERT INTO CONTRATOALUGUER (CLIENT_ID, AUTOMOVEL_ID) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound] 
    

-----------------------Entity Code Below-----------

    package isep.eapli.demo_orm.domain;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.util.List;

    @Entity
    public class ContratoAluguer {

    @OneToOne
    private Automovel automovel;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ContratoId")
    private List<CondutorAutorizado> condutorAutorizadoList;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Cliente client;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public ContratoAluguer(Automovel automovel, List<CondutorAutorizado> condutorAutorizadoList, Cliente client) {
        this.automovel = automovel;
        this.condutorAutorizadoList = condutorAutorizadoList;
        this.client = client;
    }
```

Comment: Check the constraints on this table and make sure that this particular insert is not violating those constraints.  Most likely it is.

Comment: Read also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

From error : you are trying to insert NULL value into PRIMARY KEY column, which obviously has not null constraint.
You are expecting DB to take care of generating ID for your entity - what i see from generation type strategy.
You are probably using H2 DB ? So check table definition.
Your primary key should be of type 'bigint' (http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#bigint_type).

About identity in H2, documentation says:

> Identity column is a column generated with a sequence. The column declared as the identity column with IDENTITY data type or with IDENTITY () clause is implicitly the primary key column of this table. GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, and AUTO_INCREMENT clauses do not create the primary key constraint automatically. GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY clause indicates that column can only be generated by the sequence, its value cannot be set explicitly. Identity column has implicit NOT NULL constraint. Identity column may not have DEFAULT or ON UPDATE expressions.

So your SQL should looks something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
     ID BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     ...);
```

I ma guessing you are using JPA (from the annotations). So if you are letting JPA to generate table for you, check table in H2 console as i mentioned earlier.

This would be my first step from information you provided.
Hope this helps

Comment: My primary key is type BIGINT I'll show you the sql table:

create table GRUPOAUTOMOVEL
(
    ID        BIGINT auto_increment
        primary key,
    CLASSE    VARCHAR,
    NPORTAS   INTEGER,
    NOMEGRUPO VARCHAR,
    PRECODIA  DOUBLE
);

And yes Im using H2 for the database

Comment: Since you are using generationtype INDETITY, why use auto_increment instead of identity, use GENERATED AS IDENTITY. Otherwise, why not to use Auto strategy, since you are using auto_increment ? 
Next step : make sure H2 can use this generation type. I found issue in H2 github referencing to this same problem. Maybe try to use older version like 1.4.200
Here is the issue : https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3429